# Column Not found in a Liquibase mapped database

Tags: spring, hibernate, liquibase

When trying to run tests on my spring-boot application, i get the following exception :

> org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException:
>   Schema-validation: missing column [value] in table [T_ANSWER]

my configuration looks as follows :

```
@Bean(destroyMethod = "shutdown")
    @Profile("!" + Constants.SPRING_PROFILE_CLOUD)
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        log.debug("Configuring Datasource");
        if (propertyResolver.getProperty("url") == null && propertyResolver.getProperty("databaseName") == null) {
            log.error("Your database connection pool configuration is incorrect! The application" +
                    "cannot start. Please check your Spring profile, current profiles are: {}",
                    Arrays.toString(env.getActiveProfiles()));

            throw new ApplicationContextException("Database connection pool is not configured correctly");
        }
        HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
        config.setDataSourceClassName(propertyResolver.getProperty("dataSourceClassName"));
        if (propertyResolver.getProperty("url") == null || "".equals(propertyResolver.getProperty("url"))) {
            config.addDataSourceProperty("databaseName", propertyResolver.getProperty("databaseName"));
            config.addDataSourceProperty("serverName", propertyResolver.getProperty("serverName"));
        } else {
            config.addDataSourceProperty("url", propertyResolver.getProperty("url"));
        }
        config.addDataSourceProperty("user", propertyResolver.getProperty("username"));
        config.addDataSourceProperty("password", propertyResolver.getProperty("password"));

        //MySQL optimizations, see https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/MySQL-Configuration
        if ("com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource".equals(propertyResolver.getProperty("dataSourceClassName"))) {
            config.addDataSourceProperty("cachePrepStmts", propertyResolver.getProperty("cachePrepStmts", "true"));
            config.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSize", propertyResolver.getProperty("prepStmtCacheSize", "250"));
            config.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSqlLimit", propertyResolver.getProperty("prepStmtCacheSqlLimit", "2048"));
            config.addDataSourceProperty("useServerPrepStmts", propertyResolver.getProperty("useServerPrepStmts", "true"));
        }
        return new HikariDataSource(config);
    }


  @Bean
  public SpringLiquibase liquibase(DataSource dataSource) {
    SpringLiquibase liquibase = new SpringLiquibase();
    liquibase.setDataSource(dataSource);
    liquibase.setChangeLog("classpath:config/liquibase/master.xml");
    liquibase.setContexts("development, production");
    if (env.acceptsProfiles(Constants.SPRING_PROFILE_FAST)) {
      if ("org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource".equals(propertyResolver.getProperty("dataSourceClassName"))) {
        liquibase.setShouldRun(true);
        log.warn("Using '{}' profile with H2 database in memory is not optimal, you should consider switching to" +
          " MySQL or Postgresql to avoid rebuilding your database upon each start.", Constants.SPRING_PROFILE_FAST);
      } else {
        liquibase.setShouldRun(false);
      }
    } else {
      log.debug("Configuring Liquibase");
    }
    return liquibase;
  }



    @Bean
    public Hibernate4Module hibernate4Module() {
        return new Hibernate4Module();
    }
```

and my config file looks as follows :

```
spring:
    profiles:
        active: dev

    datasource:
        dataSourceClassName: org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource
        url: jdbc:h2:mem:questionnaires;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
        databaseName:
        serverName:
        username:
        password:

    jpa:
        database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
        database: H2
        openInView: false
        show_sql: true
        properties:
            hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache: true
            hibernate.cache.use_query_cache: false
            hibernate.generate_statistics: true
            hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto: update
            hibernate.cache.region.factory_class: org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory
```

the entity that causes the problem is called Answer, it doesn't have a value attribute, but some of its children do, here is the implementation of the Entity and the child in question.

Answer :

```
 @Entity
@Table(name = "T_ANSWER")
public abstract class Answer {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    private String innerID;

    public Answer(){
        innerID = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    }



    @ManyToOne
    private AnswerTab parentTab;

    public String getInnerID() {
        return innerID;
    }

    public void setInnerID(String innerID) {
        this.innerID = innerID;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public AnswerTab getParentTab() {
        return parentTab;
    }

    public void setParentTab(AnswerTab parentTab) {
        this.parentTab = parentTab;
    }
}
```

and the child that has the value attribute :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_SINGLEANSWER")
public class SingleAnswer extends Answer{


    private String value = "";

    @ManyToOne
    private AnswerRow parentRow;



    public SingleAnswer(){

    }


    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public AnswerRow getParentRow() {
        return parentRow;
    }

    public void setParentRow(AnswerRow parentRow) {
        this.parentRow = parentRow;
    }

    @Override
    public Answer copy() {
        SingleAnswer copy = new SingleAnswer();
        copy.setInnerID(getInnerID());
        copy.setValue(value);
        return copy;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if(obj instanceof SingleAnswer){
            return value.compareTo(((SingleAnswer)obj).getValue()) == 0;
        }
        return super.equals(obj);
    }
}
```

I checked the generated database and i can clearly see that the table T_ANSWER has a value attribute.

here is the liquibase changeset that creates the table :

```
<createTable tableName="t_answer">
    <column name="DTYPE" type="VARCHAR(31)">
        <constraints nullable="false"/>
    </column>
    <column autoIncrement="true" name="id" type="BIGINT(19)">
        <constraints primaryKey="true"/>
    </column>
    <column name="innerID" type="VARCHAR(255)"/>
    <column name="value" type="VARCHAR(255)"/>
    <column name="dynamic" type="BIT(1)"/>
    <column name="size" type="INT(10)"/>
    <column name="parentTab_id" type="BIGINT(19)"/>
    <column name="parentRow_id" type="BIGINT(19)"/>
    <column name="parentGroup_id" type="BIGINT(19)"/>
</createTable>
```

Comment: I think cause of this exception is because `value` is reserved keyword in Mysql (considering you are using mysql), in that case you have add `@Column` annotation on getter of `value`, like : `@Column(name = "[VALUE]", nullable = false)`

Comment: thank you that was the issue, i figured it out when i removed it and i started seeing the same issue with the column named dynamic

Answer (score 3):

I also faced same problem. It was due to camel case of table attribute name. For me it is gone away by replacing below code. I changed it in my db-config.properties file.

**spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto: validate**

to

**spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto: update**

**Note**: Whether you are using spring boot or spring metadata config file(xml), it will work.